# How to execute package in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0

I am using oracle as my back end and i have a package with 5 procedures how can i execute the package in c#, any body with an example explain please.

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949641/call-oracle-package-function-using-odbc-from-c-sharp

Comment: i have to execute 5 procedures at a time on button pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefix with user and package your stored procedure

```
  var command = new OracleCommand(connection);
  command.CommandText = "NameOfUser.NameOfPackage.NameOfStoredProcedure";
```